# updating column for all users method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a method that will update a column for all my users at a specific time. I am doing this with the 'whenever' gem but I don't really know where to place the method.

My Users table has a column with :grades that I want to update based on another method (grade). In the rails console, when I do:

```
user.update(:grades => user.grade)
```

This works fine. When I define the method within the rails console that I want like this:

```
def update_grades(users)
 users.each do |user|
  user.update(:grades => user.grade)
 end
end

@users = User.all

update_grades(@users)
```

This works as well and updates the grades for all the users.

The problem is that I don't know where to place this method for it to work in my scheduler. I tried putting it in the user.rb model file but then when I call `update_grades(@users)` it gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_grades' for main:Object
```

I changed it to remove the (@users) and try to call `update_grades` or `@users.update_grades` neither of these work and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: private method `update_grades' called for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbb753b1b58>
```

Any ideas where I can place the method so that I can call `update_grades(@users)` or `update_grades`?

Comment: is the `update_grades()` method private ?

Comment: I haven't made it private, it's just sitting in the User class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a class method on `User`

```
class User
  def self.update_grades
    all.each do |user|
      user.update(:grades => user.grade)
    end
  end
end
```

This can be called as `User.update_grades`a

Consider wrapping it in a transaction to speed it up:

```
  def self.update_grades
    transaction do
      all.each do |user|
        user.update(:grades => user.grade)
      end
    end
  end
```